# How to create a Back Button in Material Design

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I cannot find a tutorial about adding this button in the Action bar in Material Design.

[image: example image]

How can I add this into the action bar on Lollipop?

Comment: Please post some sample code to demonstrate what you've tried :)

Comment: the problem is, i cannot find anything for this in action bar with lollipop !

Comment: are you using support library? What from your activity is extended?

Comment: @Harry - i have two activity.i'm beginner.i need tutorial only...

Comment: be careful: the title is misleading, this is not the "Back" button, but the Up button. Use the correct terms.

the "Back" button is the one that every Android device has.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Material Design Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)
This will give you brief idea how to implement material app.

If you are using `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompat Theme` use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Also you may have to call `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` in same manner.
It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Do not implement Navigation drawer if you dont need it. Just use above line of code in the main activity.

Comment: thank you, accepted and it worked now with : `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 19):

try this

in on create:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in your activity class (assuming you want to close this activity)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any example about this ? i try it but Error : `Unfortunately program stoped `  give me.tnx

Comment: can you paste the tracelog from logcat

Comment: `masterphp` is trying to implement Material design. How it can be `getActionBar()`. It must be `getSupportActionBar()`. @TomerShemesh

Answer (score 3):

in your onCreate add these lines

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

for back navigation you have to define back navigation actiity on your `AndroidMnifest.xml`

```
<activity 
android:name=".CurrentActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:parentActivityName=".BackActivity">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` may produce nullpointer exception, `onCreate()` should be like this.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you have to use `Theme` of `Material Design`, and the `Theme` supports `ActionBar`, like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

**Second**, call `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` or `ToolBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`, then the `Return` icon would show.